Is there any difference between using std::is_same<T,U>::value and std::is_same_v<T,U> in any scenario?
Are there any situations in which they act differently? I am using them with constexpr.
template<typename T>
T* getptr(){ 
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T,int>::value) { return someptr;}
}

I did not find any differences when searching, and compiling and running the code always gives the same result.
I am curious if there's any way they act differently, which is not trivial?

One is defined as the other.  They are the same.

It's not really an alias, std::is_same_v<T, U> is a global constant bool (instead of class member constant bool). But it's defined to be exactly std::is_same<T, U>::value, I cannot imagine any difference between them unless you do something strange (like taking address of either).

Suffixes _v and _t for type traits is just a convenience API to reduce a bit a boiler plate. Effectively no difference (from time to time just minimum required C++ version of standard may be different).

I recall seeing sfinae friendliness affected by choice of ::type vs _t, but it's hard to recollect. I'll see if I can dig it up.

Found it! And it's even about variables (unlike I remembered) so it's even more relevant to your question. An edge case of sorts, but you did ask about any difference.

Another potential difference is the caveat "If the program adds specializations for std::is_same or std::is_same_v, the behavior is undefined."  Which would be a very naughty thing to do indeed.

The difference is minimum std version supporting them. The _v suffixes are variable templates; they don't compile without C++14 or later.

@Red.Wave std::is_same_v (as well as other _v APIs) actually requires at least C++17 (not 14).

@wohlstad yes. Just take the or later...

As you can see in the documentation std::is_same_v is defined as:
template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;

So for all practical purposes there should be no difference between the effect of using is_same<T,U>::value and is_same_v<T,U>.
is_same_v is given as a convenience API (a "Helper variable template") to enable you to write code which is more succinct.
However an important difference is that is_same_v is available only from C++17, so if you'll compile your code with an older version you will have to resort to is_same<>::value (available from C++11).
Some more esoteric differences are given in the comments above (since you asked for any difference):

As StoryTeller - Unslander Monica commented, you can encounter a SFINAE ralated difference - see this post for more info.
As Eljay commented if the program adds specializations for std::is_same or std::is_same_v, the behavior is undefined. So in principle there could be a difference if your program add a specialization (which it shouldn't anyway).

A side note:
The above is valid in general for all the _v and _t APIs for the standard type-traits.

Another sidenote that I'm not sure qualifies as a difference: You can't use the _v version with traits that themselves wants to access the value member, like std::disjunction/std::conjunction.

@TedLyngmo I understood the question to be about differences in cases where both can be used. But anyway your comment is good for completion.

Yes, it was a bit of a stretch :-)

It's not sfinae differences on different compilers, it's a sfinae difference guaranteed

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica got it - fixed.

template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;

these are always going to have the same value in any well-formed program.
But a program containing the tokens is_same_v<A,B> and is_same<A,B>::value can be subtly different.  When used in contexts where the value doesn't matter, the compiler can (and sometimes must) skip instantiating ::value.
As an example, sizeof(is_same_v<A,B>) can be determined to by 1 without instantiating ::value, as the size of a bool isn't dependent on its value; in cases where A or B are incomplete types, the compiler shouldn't even generate an error here (some compilers do).
Meanwhile, sizeof(is_same<A,B>::value) requires that ::value exist, and invoking is_same<A,B> on incomplete types isn't legal.
Even is_same_v<bool, decltype(XXX)> can differ - if XXX is is_same_v<???> then it is true without question, but if it is is_same<A,B>::value then actually instantiating is_same could be illegal.
In short, constructs that ask the type of is_same_v must bypass instantiating the template is_same, but constructs that ask the type of is_same<>::value must instantiate the template is_same.
There are less interesting differences.  Like, a template that conditionally instantiates a template and returns its ::value is possible, but you cannot take a template value as template parameter:
template<bool, template<class...>class A, template<class...>class B>, class...Ts>
struct pick: A<Ts...> {};

template<template<class...>class A, template<class...>class B>, class...Ts>
struct pick<false, A, B, Ts...>: B<Ts...> {};

then
pick<some_bool, is_same, is_base_of, X, Y>::value

can delay instantiating is_same and only do so if some_bool is true, and no such construct can exist for is_same_v in a similar way.  But this isn't a direct use of is_same_v<> vs is_same<>::value.
